# SAASCould not resolve the variable "$breadpoint" within "if $breadpoint == tablet"

Tags: sass

I am new in `Sass`. I am following one [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEZAKu09FgM) tutorial for learning `Sass`. I used exactly the same syntax which he used on his tutorial but i am getting `sass error:` `SAASCould not resolve the variable "$breadpoint" within "if $breadpoint == tablet"`.

```
@mixin responsive($breadpoint) {
  @if $breadpoint == phone {
    @media only screen and (max-width:700px){ @content; }
  }
  @else if $breadpoint == tablet {
    @media only screen and (max-width:1060px){ @content; }
  }
  @else if $breadpoint == full{
    @media only screen and (max-width:1800px){ @content; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mixin works fine. Please check the SASS compile.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. you put string when you used the global media query. Is this why I am getting error? ps: The tutorial guy did not use string.

Comment: Not yet, use `''` or not is no problem. `@include responsive(phone) ...` also works fine

Comment: Thanks mate. I will check, what have I done wrong :D